# Routing 2nd IP to guest PC in virtual box and ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have virtualbox 5 set up on ubuntu 16.04. Hosting company have provided an additional IP address through the same NIC and i am trying to forward it totally through to a guest VM (also running ubuntu 16.04). I have tried a myriad of ideas and followed tutorials here and elsewhere on the web and seem to be getting a load of conflicting information.

Fundamentally...

- What should my network/interfaces file look like (should i add the additional ip to it, and if so, how?)
- Should i enable ip forwarding in host OS?
- Do i need to route the IP using iptables?
- Should i be using bridged mode in virtualbox?
- What should the network/interfaces file look like on the host?

Would love some definitive information :)

Comment: You left out the key question: How are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  It's a dedicated server through simplyhosting.com

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use bridged mode in virtualbox and set the IP address inside the virtual box. There is nothing to configure on the host.